# Adding dependencies to React hook leads to infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update a state using the props that I received from the parent component.

But react keeps putting up warning message to add the state that is being updated to add to the dependency list while I want effect to run once only when the component mounts.

Here is the code of the component that throws the warning message:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(undefined);
  const [disableDate, setDisableDate] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const key = Object.keys(slots);
    setDisableDate([
      ...disableDate,
      {
        before: new Date(key[0]),
        after: new Date(key[key.length - 1])
      }
    ]);

    if (!_.isEmpty(slots))
      Object.keys(slots).forEach(slot => {
        if (slots[slot].length === 0) {
          const date = moment(slot)
            .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
            .toISOString(true);
          setDisableDate([...disableDate, new Date(date)]);
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

When above code is run it works fine but it always gives the following warning.

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'disableDate' and
>   'slots'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can
>   also do a functional update 'setDisableDate(d => ...)' if you only
>   need 'disableDate' in the 'setDisableDate' call 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) on both your `setDisableDate` calls, as suggested by the warning:

```js
setDisableDate(prevDisableDate => [
   ...prevDisableDate,
   {
     before: new Date(key[0]),
     after: new Date(key[key.length - 1])
   }
]);
```

```js
setDisableDate(prevDisableDate => [...prevDisableDate, new Date(date)]);
```

In that way, `disableDate` isn't used inside `useEffect` and there is no need to add it on the dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that warning message by adding the `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` line before the dependency array. In this way the `useEffect` callback will be still triggered only once but you won't see the warning message in the same time.

Just like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ... your code

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

I hope this helps!